# The type or namespace name 'sqlconnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to show data ( column field of my table) in gridview. I have added 4 using system .Data, using system .Data.Sql, using system .Data.sqlclient. using system .Data.configuration

but when I run my project error shows:

> Error  4   The type or namespace name 'sqlconnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Learning\dusra soft\datashowing in grid\datashowing in grid\grid.aspx.cs 18  9   datashowing in grid

Comment: Did you try SqlConnection? C# is case sensitive

Comment: No need of system.Data.Sql namespace,can you post the ado.net code here?

Comment: And also its SqlConnection pascal naming convention not just sqlconnection